# How to change color of a table cell based on its text for the whole web site?

Tags: asp.net, tablecell

On our web site, there are multiple pages that show prices - could be in a table defined in a user control, could be in a grid view, or could be in a data table, etc. Now I need to find a way to show the price in red if it is negative. I don't want to do it page by page, is there any way I can achieve this for the whole site? I am thinking of using themes/skins or web control adapters? Is this the right direction?

Comment: If you would like to take the jquery route here is a quick example. It sounds like you are using webforms I would suggest adding the css class on the backend it would be a cleaner solution.   

http://benjaminjshore.info/2014/03/jquery-change-css-upon-table-value.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this purpose to get table cell value and validate it. Got this in following link (by Mottie). Check the fiddle demo in that site.

```
$('table td').each(function(){
var t = $(this),
val = parseInt( t.text(), 10 );
if (val < 0 ) { t.addClass(negative); }   
});
```

css

```
.negative { background: red; }
```

[**site link with code and fiddle**](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/setting-backround-color-of-tablecell-dynamically/)

change this according to your requirement. Parse the text of td to integer if necessary and if it is negative apply the css

Comment: How do I apply this for the whole site? or I need put this function for each page?

Comment: Add this on to your site.master page. I am guessing you have placeholders for your page contents.